# How to create optimized GIF animation for a presentation?

Tags: performance, presentations, gif, animated-gif

I need to include in my PowerPoint presentation an animation which has about 1000 frames. I know there is a possibility to optimize a GIF animation in such a way that each next frame contains only changed portion of an image as compared to the previous frame. But I do not know which programs are able to do this. I have tried GIF Movie Gear - it is good but saves only 10% by optimization. I think there must be better solutions. Can anybody recommend a tool?

**UPDATE**

I have tried [Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) 1.63 (command `-O2 -b -k 128 --careful anim.gif`) and found that it generates a little bigger file than GIF Movie Gear and this file renders with artifacts in IrfanView but without artifacts in Power Point.

Comment: Does it have to be a single (optimally animated) picture in max 256 colours? Because that is what gif is.  Or can it be a movie (with dozens of formats to choose from, e.g. mpeg)

Comment: @Hennes I need any format that is natively supported by PowerPoint. As far as I know the only such trouble-free format is GIF. It is also possible to include Flash animation in PowerPoint slides but probably it will require Flash to be installed and that is inappropriate for me.

Answer (score 1):

"optimize a GIF animation in such a way that each next frame contains only changed portion of an image as compared to the previous frame"
The [Gif Screen Recorder](http://gifrecorder.com) does exactly that. To get the compression with current version you have to open your gif in a player such as your browser and let the Gif Screen Recorder record the animation. The new animation will have the compression applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Trouts GIF Optizer](http://chemware.co.nz/tgo.htm).

> Trout's GIF Optimizer shrinks GIFs without any noticable reduction of picture quality

Comment: I have tried Trout's GIF Optimizer. It is not able to reduce file size at all. It seems that the only optimization method it provides is reducing the color palette and this can be done even better with GIF Movie Gear. It does not have a feature that compares each frame to the previous frame and discards any pixels that do not change across frames.